# How to switch every two elements in a vector in R?

Tags: r, vector

For example I have a vector as follows:

```
FOL.2. FOL TAL.2. TAL BOR.2. BOR HAD.2. HAD ITA.2. ITA NOR.2. NOR
```

I need the vector to be as follows:

```
FOL FOL.2. TAL TAL.2. BOR BOR.2. HAD HAD.2. ITA ITA.2. NOR NOR.2.
```

I tried `sort(myvector)` but it doesn't work. Basically I need to switch the positions of every two elements in the vector.Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution

```
x[1:length(x) + c(1, -1)]
```

The operation in `[]` converts `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` to `2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5`.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a matrix and then coerce

```
c(matrix(v1, nrow = 2)[2:1,])
#[1] "FOL"    "FOL.2." "TAL"    "TAL.2." "BOR"    "BOR.2." "HAD"    "HAD.2." "ITA"    "ITA.2." "NOR"    "NOR.2."
```

#### data

```
v1 <- scan(text = "FOL.2. FOL TAL.2. TAL BOR.2. BOR HAD.2. HAD ITA.2. ITA NOR.2. NOR", what = "")
```